# Right-Click Context Menu in System Tray

Tags: wpf, contextmenu

I have a WPF app that runs in the system tray. I'm trying to create a context menu that pops up when you right click on the icon in the tray. Here is the XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="NotifierContextMenu" Placement="MousePoint">
            <MenuItem Header="Exit" Click="Menu_Exit"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Window.Resources>
```

And here is the code-behind:

```
void NotifyIcon_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                var menu = this.FindResource("NotifierContextMenu") as ContextMenu;
                menu.IsOpen = true;
            }
        }

        protected void Menu_Exit(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            NotifyIcon.Visible = false;
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }
```

The issue that I'm having is that when you right-click on the icon, it throws an error that NotifierContextMenu can't be found. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this myself with no problems.  Your event handler for the MouseDown is in fact part of the same class that NotifierContextMenu is created right?

Perhaps try making a little code to list out the resources to see if you can match up which resource set it is referring to.

Comment: Yes, they're in the same class. I am running Parallel.Foreach code in this app, when I comment that out it works fine. Any idea how to get it working?

Comment: Any possibility that the ForEach is causing problems on that thread?  Can you try creating a BackgroundWorker and put the Parallel.ForEach stuff in that to move it off onto a different thread?  I have never used Parallel.ForEach, but it is related to a bunch of threading stuff in MSDN.  Just a thought.